# Pre-defining the constructor value to none..when not given

Tags: python

I'm creating a `Node` class that takes some parameters. One is called `next` which I would like to be set as `None` by the constructor if no value is supplied.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, next,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def X(self):
    node = Node(next ,data)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a default value for it in function header  `__init__(self,data,next=None)`

Comment: Read up on default values [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Comment: As an aside, what is the `Node.X` method for? It's not doing anything useful here. And by the way, it's not indented properly.

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of the parameters to `__init__()` and give next a default value.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def X(self):
        node = Node(data)


node_a = Node('A')
node_b = Node('B', node_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap your arguments, and give `next` a default:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

then simply not pass in a next node when creating one:

```
def foo():
    node = Node(data)
```

or pass in another node as the second argument:

```
def bar():
    node = Node(data, some_other_node)
```